# CSS navigation bar: spacing issue

Tags: css

for some unknown reason, my navigation bar is shifted over to the right, on Firefox and also on Chrome. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/dskZy.png

And what's weird is that the issue doesn't arise on jsfiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/bMAGX/

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a [**CSS Reset**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)? I'm guessing not. You should consider using one to help with issues like this.

I think you need this CSS to remove the default `ul` margin/padding:

```
#topmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

Comment: @Dave2 ... And jsfiddle actually uses a CSS reset on their site, which is why you didn't see it there.

Comment: @mercator: Good to spell that out, I should have included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because your DOCTYPE is malformed.

`<!DOCTYPE html>` should be one of the types defined [here](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Comment: *Not my downvote*, but your answer is simply wrong. There's no problem with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Good to know. I just discovered that this is a HTML 5 standard! Thanks :)

Comment: But do the current versions of Chrome and Firefox support HTML 5 yet?

Comment: "All browsers" (IE 6/7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) support (will go into Standards Mode with) the HTML5 doctype. See: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to top of your CSS:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

Comment: It's best to avoid the star selector if possible. Here, it's possible to use a CSS Reset instead of that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful