# difference between body and * in css

Tags: css

what is the difference between

```
body{
  background: #4b4b4b;
}
```

and

```
*{
    background: #4b4b4b;
 }
```

which has higher priority?

Comment: You might want to go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful

Comment: I also feel using * is evil. Even if it does its job properly. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in applying CSS to html, body, and the universal selector \*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/difference-in-applying-css-to-html-body-and-the-universal-selector)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `body` selector has higher priority, but the `*` selector applies more broadly, so in `<body>foo<p>bar</p></body>` the `body` selector will determine the background of the text `foo`, but the `*` selector will determine the background of the `<p>` element.

Note, also that many browsers create an element around the `<body>` that includes its margins and scrollbars, so the `*` selector may also determine the color of that region.

Comment: Can we use body and * in same design or is it suggestable to use only one like either it has to be body or *.

Comment: @GladwinJames, If you want to match one thing then `body` is preferable to `*`.  This matters when style properties multiply as in `<style>*{font-size: 150%}</style><body><div>a<div>b<div>c<div>d<div>e`. Also be aware of [:root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root) which is a good alternative to `body`.

Answer (score 9):

`body` selects the body element, `*` selects *all* elements.

Out of those two, `body` has higher priority.

Comment: Using body is better than using * if the purpose using setting background color.

Answer (score 9):

**What is the difference?**

`body` is an element selector (selects an element `body`) while `*` is a universal selector (selects all elements).

**Which has higher specificity (the proper term for priority)?**

When calculating specificity of a selector (Think of it as a binary number):

- If it's an inline style declaration you add `1000`.
- For every id attribute value you add `0100`.
- For every class attribute value, attribute selection or pseudo-class you add `0010`
- For every element and pseudo element you add `0001`.
- For every combinator or universal selector you add `0000`.
- If it's an inherited declartion it has no specificity.

Thus the specificity of `body` is `0001` and the specificity of `*` is `0000`. `body` wins.

Answer (score 4):

Some HTML elements have a default background color, such as `<input>`, `<select>`, etc. Using `*` will affect them as well instead of only the `<body>` and all children with a transparent background.

Comment: `*{ background: #4b4b4b; }` will not only affect elements with a default background, it'll simpy affect all elements that can have a background color

Comment: @Mark: how exactly did I said otherwise?

Comment: thought you were implying it'll only affect the elements that have a default background color (like the form elements you mentioned) but offcourse it'll also color the background of for example (a normally transparent) div element

Comment: @Mark: uh yes, maybe you missed the "instead of" part?

Answer (score 0):

1. do not use * universal selector and it is not a standard way
2. body background applies only full body background and * background means apply same background to all element inside body
3. now a days in css3 uses reset css and main style css separately

Comment: Actually, the universal selector (*) selects all elements _including_ `body`.