# Is avoiding duplicate declarations considered good practice in this case?

Tags: css

Is it recommended to combine equal declarations in CSS in order to reduce the filesize and avoiding duplications?

For Example:

```
#topbar,#searchbox.focus,#usermenu li:hover a,#cart-flyout-table tbody td,.btn_remove:hover,#heading-warenkorb a:hover,.button:hover span,.input-text:focus,#pages li a:hover,select:focus,.picture-overview li:hover,#category-sub li a:hover {background-color:#e3eed3}
```

Is it recommended to do this for some other Properties which are used very often like float,text-align or padding for example?

The Code would getting harder to read and edit but if this will be done only for the most common properties I would accept it. What's about the performance at the rendering? Would it make my website faster or slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The answer is: varies.

In general, I would only recommend on doing that when the elements in question are **similar** in *content* or in *area*. I'll explain.

let's say you have a sidebar, and that sidebar has several headlines in it, which you wish to have similar stylings. That's perfectly acceptable to use `aside h1, aside h2, aside h3 { font-weight: normal; color: blue; }`.

However, to use it the way you described, for a 100 different elements on different parts of the page, then I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid the type of CSS styling you mentioned.

It makes your stylesheets much harder to read and update.

Instead, I would group styles according to sections of the page

`nav`, `header`, `content`, etc.

or by actions

`form`, `call to actions`, etc.

or a combo of both.

If you see some duplication within those categories, then combining would be fine.

Otherwise, for example, if you want to update one `a`, you may need to look in four or more different places (for link, active, visited, and hover).

Answer (score 0):

i can't see any problem in combining declaration.

Yet, if you want to apply the **same style to your whole page**, you'd better considering calling `body { }` or  `* { }`.

Details to choose between these two are described here: [difference between body and * in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890342/difference-between-body-and-in-css)

---

You may also consider using [classes](http://www.pageresource.com/dhtml/csstut4.htm) or [css inheritance](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-inheritance-cascade/) to avoid so many combination

Comment: If I would use a class for this how should it be called? .bg-light-green? I have learned to avoid names like this.

Comment: in this particular case, it might not be a good idea. what i meant is you have to take into account the whole styling of your HTML in order to reduce this kind of statement. Meaningly, where do you want to have *light-green*? can you set the style on a parent element? is there anyway to refactor the **common** parts of your style (and not only light-green)... This kind of css statement is hard to refactor and maintain, especially if you have many of these

Comment: This color is used for many Elemnts at completely different locations in Magento. Some Elements are part of the layout-frame and some others are just hover states of buttons or list-items. This causes the quantity of different selectors. Just the color is the same every time.

Comment: ok, i understand. Believing Jason answer, you should group styles, i think that's the best way to deal with your case