# Difference in applying CSS to html, body, and the universal selector *?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How are these three rules different when applied to the same HTML document?

```css
html {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

body {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

* {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: same except no mention of `*` (which is "trivial"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element

Comment: same on programmers asked later: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178049/css-use-universal-selector-vs-html-or-body-selector

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34698257/3597276

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. ```css
   html {
       color: black;
       background-color: white;
   }
   ```

   This rule applies the colors to the `html` element. All descendants of the `html` element inherit its `color` (but not `background-color`), including `body`. The `body` element has no default background color, meaning it's transparent, so `html`'s background will show through until and unless you set a background for `body`.

   Although the background of `html` is painted over the entire viewport, the `html` element itself does not span the entire height of the viewport automatically; the background is simply propagated to the viewport. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085911/106224) for details.
2. ```css
   body {
       color: black;
       background-color: white;
   }
   ```

   This rule applies the colors to the `body` element. All descendants of the `body` element inherit its `color`.

   Similarly to how the background of `html` is propagated to the viewport automatically, the background of `body` will be propagated to `html` automatically, until and unless you set a background for `html` as well. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10947583/106224) for an explanation. Because of this, if you only need one background (in usual circumstances), whether you use the first rule or the second rule won't make any real difference.

   You can, however, combine background styles for `html` and `body` with other tricks to get some nifty background effects, like [I've done here](http://dev.NOVALISTIC.com). See the above linked answer for how.
3. ```css
   * {
       color: black;
       background-color: white;
   }
   ```

   This rule applies the colors to *every element*, so neither of the two properties is implicitly inherited. But you can easily override this rule with anything else, including either of the above two rules, as `*` has literally no significance in selector specificity.

   Because this breaks the inheritance chain completely for any property that is normally inherited such as `color`, setting those properties in a `*` rule is considered bad practice unless you have a *very* good reason to break inheritance this way (most use cases that involve breaking inheritance require you to do it for just one element, not *all* of them).

Comment: Note that by default, the `body` also usually has a small margin, which `html` does not.

Comment: Which type of element is <body>? Block Level Or inline?

Comment: @SteveJorgensen, it's actually a small padding; otherwise, the background wouldn't expand to the whole page.

Comment: @zneak: Actually, it *is* a margin. The `body` element doesn't really "expand" to cover the whole page; rather, the `html` element uses the `body` element's background if its own background color is computed as `transparent` and/or its background image is computed as `none`. This is described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#special-backgrounds). This means if you take a default page and set different backgrounds for `html` and `body`, you'll notice that the `body` is in fact being offset by a margin rather than padding its content.

Comment: @zneak: You can also apply a background and a border to `body` alone to see the margin: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/vddbh