# Why doesn't the html element take up the whole browser viewport?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a website.  Many people claim that the `html` element expands to the whole viewport.  When I do code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
Hi
</body>
</html>
```

The border shows up only in the top part of the screen where it says "Hi".  Isn't `html` supposed to default to fit the entire screen in a browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite being the root element, `html` has no special attributes in terms of CSS; it is a regular block box in the normal flow, and block boxes by default don't have an intrinsic height. The default height is `auto`; the specific details of how `auto` is calculated are described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#normal-block), but basically for in-flow block boxes this means as tall as their contents require, and no more. The same applies to the `body` element.

Note that if you specify a background color for `html`, that background color will propagate or "bleed" onto the entire viewport, although the height of `html` does not change. This behavior is intentional (the background can also be propagated from `body` to `html` in a similar manner); see my answers to these related questions for an explanation:

- [<html> width is less than its background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083984/html-width-is-less-than-its-background)
- [Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body)

Note, also, that the behavior you expect, i.e.,

> Isn't `html` supposed to default to fit the entire screen in a browser?

does apply in quirks mode and to very old versions of IE (older than 6); mostly a consequence of poor adherence to poorly defined web standards (this was a time when the original CSS2 recommendation was published, and CSS itself was still in its infancy). That is, the `html` and `body` elements are indeed both 100% of the viewport height in quirks mode, and the aforementioned behavior of `html` and `body` defaulting to content height only applies in standards mode.

Comment: I have heard that the difference between the body tag and the html tag is that the BODY element may not always hit the 'bottom' of the viewport.  In this case, the html tag isn't hitting it either.  What is the point of the html tag if it doesn't consider the viewport of the browser?

Comment: @AnimalTesting: The point of the html element is that it is the root element of an HTML document. It has nothing to do with how it is displayed, but because the DOM consists of a body element as the child of an html element, the browser needs to ensure at the very minimum that both elements are displayed as blocks for the layout to function.

Comment: Is there a default tag that has something to do with the browser viewport?

Comment: @AnimalTesting: No, the document canvas is not represented by any element, not even the root element.

Comment: So essentially html and body are just divs, one absolute and one relative?

Comment: @AnimalTesting: Yes, although technically they are neither, i.e. not positioned at all. But they do appear at the origin of the viewport as part of the normal flow.

Answer (score 2):

No. The `html` and `body` tag have a default value of `auto` for its height. So you will need to do something like

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Just the background of these elements are rendered by default for the full size of the screen.

Comment: Can you explain why html doesn't default to width and height 100% then?

Comment: It says on the webpage that: •The html element's height and width are controlled by the browser window.  If it was, why would I need to set height to 100% then?

Comment: Because its a block-level entity. Just as if you had a parent div of a certain height and a child div with a default height of auto, the child div is not going to automatically be set to 100% height of its parent.

Comment: So even though the html tag does extend out as far as the viewport goes and no further, it does not have to as long as there isn't enough content?

Comment: @AnimalTesting: The statement from that webpage seems to be inaccurate.

Comment: @alex - Boltclock's comment above is correct. There's quite a bit wrong with that phrogz article. It's not a bad description of how things work in quirks mode, but in standards mode things work quite differently, so I advise against recommending it as a modern guide.