# Mechanics: Why does it take 3 height: 100% tags to make a background fill screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn the basic mechanics that explain why it takes 3 `height: 100%` tags to fill the screen with a background image.  Intuitively I understand why `.bg` needs `height: 100%`  or alternately `height: 100vh;`However I don't understand why the `BODY` tag needs `height: 100%` and I especially don't understand why the `HTML` tag also needs it.  If any one of these 3 lines is deleted the effect stops working.  Is there something in the spec that explains this?  I can't find it.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pmyx49j/)

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.bg { 
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/600x600);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">   
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Fran how did you do that awesome edit?  That helps to keep the code on the page.

Comment: There is a snippet button in the toolbar which brings up a UI, similar to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .bg div is inside both the body and the html tags. Since it's height:100% fills its parent's height, the parent tags, html and body must also be the full height:100%. If they are not then even though the .bg div is filling height:100%, that 100% comes from a parent which is not the full screen height, so .bg is only able to fill whatever the parent's height was.

Comment: So `HTML` and `BODY` snap down just like any other `DIV`.  Interesting.  I had thought they were kind of inert elements.

Comment: Try setting HTML or BODY to 50% and you will see that the height of the div fills 100% of that, but the Body/Html fills only half the screen.

Comment: @DR01D I'm not sure what you mean by inert but they're only as tall as the content inside it (assuming that content isn't pulled out of the flow of the document) and your only content is two empty divs. [MDN article on height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

Comment: @BSMP: I assume inert means fixed at 100% viewport height or something. This is actually the case in quirks mode, so their original intuition isn't far off.

Comment: Sure enough I changed that line to `height:50%` in both the `BODY` and `HTML` elements and they acted like any other parent.  I had previously thought that `HTML` didn't do much except get the document started.  Very interesting.

Comment: @DR01D: Page rendering is defined in terms of CSS, so CSS layout has to be defined for every element, including the root element html. But in terms of content height there are no special layout rules for html or body, which means they behave just like a regular div. Also see [Why doesn't the html element take up the whole browser viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599919/why-doesnt-the-html-element-take-up-the-whole-browser-viewport)

Comment: @BoltClock  Yep I just checked and even the border tag works fine on the `HTML` element.  I had previously always left that element alone.  Great link!