# Changing the background color and width of the body element

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to set the background for the `body` element. I've changed the width of `body`, and I expect the background to fit in this width, but instead it's filling the whole screen. How would I fix it?

```css
body {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: black;
}
```

Comment: See also [Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body) and [<html> width is less than its background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083984/html-width-is-less-than-its-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually doing it, except when you don't declare a background color for the `html` element, it then takes the background color of the `body` element. Hence, you're not seeing the difference.

Simply give the `html` element a different background color, and also give `body` some `height`:

```css
html {
    background-color: red;     /* new */
}

body {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;              /* new */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
}
```

---

**Understanding the relationship between `html`, `body` and `background-color`.**

The initial `background-color` for all elements is [**`transparent`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-color).

If the `background-color` of the `html` element is not specified (i.e., `transparent`) then, under the rules of CSS, the browser gives it the `background-color` of the `body` element.

*From the spec:*

> [**3.11.2. The Canvas Background and the HTML `<body>`
>   Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#body-background)
>
> For documents whose root element is an HTML `HTML` element or an XHTML
>   `html` element: if the computed value of `background-image` on the
>   root element is `none` and its `background-color` is `transparent`,
>   user agents must instead propagate the computed values of the
>   background properties from that element's first HTML `BODY` or XHTML
>   `body` child element. The used values of that `BODY` element's
>   background properties are their initial values, and the propagated
>   values are treated as if they were specified on the root element. It
>   is recommended that authors of HTML documents specify the canvas
>   background for the `BODY` element rather than the `HTML` element.

Comment: Ah. I see. So the HTML mimics the background of the body, when none is declared for itself. I never knew that. ;P

Comment: While you're here, though, do you know if there's a way to apply css to all elements except the body in a single go?

Comment: I updated my answer with more details about `html` and `background-color`.

Comment: To target all elements except `body` you could try something like this: `body  *`. This targets all descendants of the `body` element.

Comment: Thanks. If you're still here, I've asked a new question on a new topic. If you're interested in answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388228/z-index-not-working-for-fixed-element