# z-index not working for fixed element

Tags: html, css, z-index, fixed

I was working on my code when I stumbled upon this fun fact:

*`z-index` doesn't work for a fixed element and, therefore, fixed elements will always be in front.*

Is there a way to place a non-fixed element in front of a fixed element?

Thanks.

```css
#fixed {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
#normal {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'fixed'> I'm Fixed </div>
<div id = 'normal'> I'm Normal </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you're dealing with flex items or grid items, an element must be positioned for `z-index` to work.<sup>1</sup>

In other words, the `position` property must have a value other than `static` or `z-index` will be ignored.<sup>2</sup>

Your second div is not positioned. Here are two options:

- add `position: relative` to `#normal`, or
- give the positioned div a negative `z-index` value

```css
#fixed {
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;                   /* a negative value here will also work */
}
#normal {
    background-color: lightblue;      
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;           /* new */
}
```

```html
<div id = 'fixed'> I'm Fixed </div>
<div id = 'normal'> I'm Normal </div>
```

See also: [**Basics of the CSS `z-index` property**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276)

---

<sup>1</sup> Although `z-index`, as defined in [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index), applies only to positioned elements, CSS 3 allows `z-index` to work with [grid items](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) and [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting), even when `position` is `static`.

<sup>2</sup> [`z-index` property page at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Answer (score 1):

Use negative `z-index` for the fixed element.

```
<div id = 'fixed'> I'm Fixed </div>
<div id = 'normal'> I'm Normal </div>

#fixed {
background-color: red;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1;
}
#normal {
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#fixed {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
#normal {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'fixed'> I'm Fixed </div>
<div id = 'normal'> I'm Normal </div>
```

```css
#fixed {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
#normal {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'fixed'> I'm Fixed </div>
<div id = 'normal'> I'm Normal </div>
```