# Background color stays white for html page

Tags: html, css

Background colour does not change.
Have tried setting html height to 100% as well but background refuses to change colour.
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Templates\style.css">
    <title>Tal.Ly</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: @esQmo_ Nope, it didnt work :(

Comment: Well, try answers from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698257/why-doesnt-background-color-on-body-work

Comment: And : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body

Comment: It doesn't matter if it doesn't contain anything... @esQmo_