# What is the difference between applying CSS to <body> and Universal Selector (*)

Tags: css

Is there any difference between applying CSS to body tag and universal selector (*).
Which scenario will take precedence while applying specificity rules.

Comment: `*` is less specific than any tag selector, but it applies to *every* element. `body` just applies to one. Big difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between body and \* in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890342/difference-between-body-and-in-css)

Answer (score 3):

Applying styles with the universal selector will apply the code to **every** element

Applying styles to the body will only affect the body but other elements *may* inherit those styles

The specificity of the Universal Selector is the lowest you can use. More info on this can be found in the [W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)

Answer (score 0):

body is for body and (`*`) is for (`*`) ? x)
If some code ( i hope not) is not in the body, the CSS still apply :)

Comment: Stop with those smileys

Answer (score 0):

The selector `(*)` is used for all elements of the page (head, body ...). However, if you apply the body tag, only the body elements have been modified.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this example:

```
body{ 
  background-color: red;
}
.random-class{
  background-color: green;
}
.second-random-class{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

is not the same as

```
* {
  background-color: red
}
.random-class{
  background-color: green;
}
.second-random-class{
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

since the `*` selector will apply the `background-color` to **EVERY** element.

The `*`-selector with `background-color: red` will result in

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
.random-class{
  background-color: green;
}
.second-random-class{
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: red; // <-- received this from *
}
```

Note that this will NEVER appear like this in the source code (at least if you are not using SCSS or LESS or a similar preprocessor). This is just how the hierachy is defined.

Comment: Your final example is slightly askew. CSS property/values apply in order of appearance, one of the reasons it's called `'cascading`. your random class background-color doesn't change to red. For that to happen you would need something like `!important` in your `* { } ` statement

Comment: You're right. I was also wondering... Found a little fail in my testsuite. I'll change it!

Answer (score 0):

As other's have pointed out `*` searches for all elements. In short, anytime you specify a specific tag, the tag will naturally target it's own environment. However, another reason is because the `html` selector is considered the root of any document and the `body` is a descendant. So `* {}` !== all elements in `html, body {}` Therefore, as you inquired, `*` does not equal `<body>`. Furthermore, what's even more interesting is that `:root` and `html` both target the same thing, except that `:root` has a higher priority over it's `html` counterpart.

See [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element) There are only 2 elements that descend from the `HTML` root `<head>` and `<body>`. See [body spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element)

Here is a short snippet to help visualize:

```css
* {
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}

:root {
  /* i have higher priority over html {} */
  background-color: pink;
}

html {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>
  test
</p>
<div>
  test2
</div>
<footer>
  Copyright &copy; 2018
</footer>
```