# Why We Use "*" Selector Instead Of Body Element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I was searching about `*` sign and what does it mean then I know now what does it means ... But why we don't use `body` element instead of it so that it will select all elements in the `body` element.

Comment: You can use `body` if you want. But `*` works for all elements, not only `body`.

Comment: This question was already answered: [Here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890342/difference-between-body-and-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` means a property/setting is applied to *all elements*, whereas *not all* elements necessarily inherit all properties/settings from `body`

Comment: Thanks!, I was so helpful