# Override properties

Tags: css

I have a class `*`, but I can't override the proporties in this class later on? Why...?

```
* {
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#3c6b93;
}
```

eg

```
.test {
    font-size:17px;
    color:red;
}
```

only way the `.test` class can override is I delete each specific proporty in the `*` class

Comment: It's working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/FnS8A/ .... probably there are some other errors i.e., typo in class names....

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is this: http://jsfiddle.net/fPxcq/ (note <span>). Solution: Do not use `*` selector.

Comment: @Floem - While I don't necessarily disagree, adding another `*` to the `.test` declaration resolves that. The problem is, where does it end? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/fPxcq/1/

Comment: if its a bad idea to use the `*` selector, what are the alternatives?

Comment: @clarkk - Have you looked into [CSS Resets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)?

Comment: @clarkk Well `body` since those properties "trickle down" (descendants inherit them)...

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful/1714210#1714210 first comment (by ApoY2k) explains it nicely.

Comment: @sime, post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I do it:

```
body {
    font:11px/1.2 Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color:#3c6b93;
}

.test {
    font-size:17px;
    color:red;
}
```

The above properties trickle down (to descendant elements). Therefore, you define the most general rules on the `body` element. Now, unless overridden, those rules will apply to all elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
                font-family:tahoma;
                font-size:11px;
                color:#3c6b93;
        }
        .test {
            font-size:17px;
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Text</div>
    <div class="test">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

works as expected in my browser.