# Why does a class property not override the Universal Property?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB';
}
```

I have put the above one at the top of my CSS and

```css
.table-dark {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
}
```

this above one at the end.

I am using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29).

Over here, only the `font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB';` is being used by the browser, but not the last one, i.e., `font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;`

I want to use the last one. Now, what should I do?

Comment: also used body > div > .jumbotron.table-dark{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - Cannot override P.class because of \* definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463466/css-cannot-override-p-class-because-of-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're bumping into the crux of cascading, and the reason a lot of people avoid the wildcard selector.

The wildcard selector applies to all objects, and it isn't applying the style as an inheritance. You may assume that `*{}` is really affecting the `<html>` or `<body>` elements, but in actually it is applying directly to *all* elements. Because of this, `*{}` has higher specificity than an inherited style from the element's parent.

`.table-dark` is a container class, because of this, you likely have `<tbody>`, `<tr>`, and `<td>` elements between it and the content. This is stopping the `<table>` element from passing its font on. Think of it like this:

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
}
table {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<body> <!-- helvetica -->
  <div> <!-- inherited helvetica -->
    <table> <!-- arial -->
      <tbody> <!-- inherited arial -->
        <tr> <!-- inherited arial -->
          <td> <!-- inherited arial -->
            content <!-- inherited arial -->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here, the `<body>` is passing Helvetica to the `<div>`, however it is *not* passing it to the table, because table is defined in the CSS. However, you've assigned it to *all* elements, like this:

```css
* {
  font-family: helvetica;
}
table {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<body> <!-- helvetica -->
  <div> <!-- helvetica -->
    <table> <!-- arial -->
      <tbody> <!-- helvetica -->
        <tr> <!-- helvetica -->
          <td> <!-- helvetica -->
            content <!-- helvetica -->
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You. This definition along with example was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Child elements don't inherit `font-family` by default.

It will work if you have text directly inside `.table-dark`. If your text is wrapped by other elements (the `p` tag for instance), the `*` CSS rule will take precedence, and you wouldn't need `!important` either.

Created a sample here,

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.table-dark {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
```

```html
<div class="table-dark">
  This is Times New Roman
  <p> This is Helvetica </p>
</div>
```

You can read more about [CSS specificity here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS renders when the page loads, so it will override the ".table-dark" style, because there are still some elements after the ".table-dark" div.

Try avoid using * for changing styles. Instead you could use "body" or "main".

See snippet below:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB';
}
.table-dark{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
      <div>header: Berlin Sans FB Text</div>
      <div class="table-dark">
          'Times New Roman' Text
      </div>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element isn't going to inherit the `font-family` property because you've already given it its `font-family` property using the universal selector.