# z index ie 7 dialog div

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Text in a dialog div is appearing under the text on the page only in IE 7.

See this 
[page](http://www-test.flypeach.com/newsletter/registration.aspx)
and click on any of the text boxes on the left hand side.

I tried changing the z-index in the skin.css file on the div.dialogFromAndTo element but this has no effect.

Comment: You might want to check out this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this for IE 7 only, its a hack but works, is there any better way?

```
*  {
  *z-index:13; 
}
```

Comment: using the * selector is considered harmful in terms of performance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful
If z-index worked to fix your layout issue, try making it as specific as possible

Comment: @luca Thats the thing , im not sure which element to target.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to clearFix your `<div id="dialogFrom">` as there are elements in there that are floated.

this old article: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html explains the concept and you can find different ways to apply the clearFix method by googling it

EDIT try adding this:

```
div.dialogFromAndTo {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

or possibly `zoom: 1` to trigger hasLayout - I don't know if you have it already as I can't access your page at the moment

Comment: I tried that didnt change anything. I put `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in the bottom of the div like in the article.

Comment: I've edited my answers with another couple of options that might work - might not, sorry I could not test them beforehand, they're almost a shoot in the dark

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions, i tried them , did not work.