# CSS selectors Descendant selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I couldnt understand the below from **W3C spec.**

> **div * p**
>
> matches a P element that is a grandchild or later descendant of a DIV element. Note the white space on either side of the "*" is not part of the universal selector; **the white space is a combinator indicating that the DIV must be the ancestor of some element**, and that that element must be an ancestor of the P.

How the white space is a combinator indicating that the DIV must be the ancestor of some element?

Please help to clarify

Comment: *sidenote:* Avoid using `*` in CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful/1714151#1714151

Comment: There is nothing called `whitespace` in CSS. You write `div*p` and `div * p` selects the same thing. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: div*p and div * p both won't work http://jsfiddle.net/qEfz2/

Comment: A selector is a chain of one or more simple selectors separated by combinators. Combinators are: white space, ">", and "+". White space may appear between a combinator and the simple selectors around it.

Comment: @C-Link you are half wrong.. http://jsfiddle.net/qEfz2/2/

Comment: @Mr_Green Oh! yeah, you are right. Thanks for informing that....

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: `div*p` is invalid and won't select anything. `div * p` selects `p` that is at least two levels down from a `div`. The term whitespace is confusing here, because whitespace is often thought of to be insignificant, but in this case it is very significant.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Even if your statement that `div*p` and `div * p` worked the same was true, then you just pretty much defined exactly what whitespace is: space characters that don't mean anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to first understand how CSS rules are interpreted by the browser.

Whenever you write a CSS selector, you can use one or many elements in the selector. For instance, the selector `div` has one element, both `div p` and `div > p` have two.

Think of a CSS selector as several stages of filtering. CSS selectors are actually interpreted by the browser reading them from right to left. When multiple elements are specified in a selector, you first find the set all the elements for the right-most piece, then filter that set by the next piece, and so on.

In the case of the `div` rule, we are saying "find me all 'div' elements on the page". Simple enough.

In the case of the `div p` rule, we first "find all the 'p' elements on the page". But then, for each of those 'p' elements, we then ask "give me just the 'p' elements that have a 'div' as an ancestor".

Using the same logic, let's describe `div * p`: we first "find all the 'p' elements on the page". Next, we ask "give me just the 'p' elements that have a parent element of any kind". From *that* set, we then ask 'give me just the elements out of this set that have a 'div' as an ancestor".

The selector `div * p` would be *almost* the same as `div p`, but with one key difference: the `<div>` would have to be at least a grandparent of the `<p>` for the selector to match. See http://jsfiddle.net/cDTGY/ for an example.

Comment: Thanks for elaborate explanation. div p ==> descendant selector. Then why there universal selector in between and white space around it?

Comment: I updated the answer to demonstrate the difference :)

Comment: Yes. Whitespace causes p to be descendant of universal operator * -:)