# How to add 55 width to everysingle object in a class

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering how I can have a `<div class = "holder"> ALL THE 200 OBJECTS</div>` and everything in there add 55px to.

Here is code that i have tried but failed.

```
$("#holder").width($("#holder").width() + 45);
```

Any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Do you want every child element of the holder div to have 55px?

Comment: if you want everything in there to be 55px then just do pure CSS .holder * {width: 55px}

Comment: You can see that in HTML, you added a class, while in jQuery script, you used `#` (id) selector. Then, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want every child of the holder div to have a width of 55px, you can do this with pure CSS, using the star selector.

```
.holder * {
  width:55px;
}
```

However be careful, the star selector is not the best. See this SO answer for more information about that: [(why) is the CSS star selector considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful)

Depending on your child elements, you could target specific child tags. For example:

```
.holder .icon,
.holder .avatar {
  width:55px;
}
```

or only direct children:

```
.holder > .icon,
.holder > .avatar {
  width:55px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to make everything uniformly 55px in width, then I'd go with the CSS solution that has already proposed, however, if you are looking to add 55px to every element of the holder class (as your question seems to indicate, as well as your JS), then you just need to modify your JS a bit:

```
$('.holder').each(function() {
  $(this).width($(this).width() + 55);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div#holder *').css("width", "+=55px");
```

or

```
$('div#holder *').width($('div#holder *').width() + 55);
```

both works.

Where `div#holder` is the *father* of elements.

---

### Remember:

`#` = id

`.` = class

If you're working with class, then the code would be `div.holder` instead `div#holder`.