# Hide element if first sibling has a specific href

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML, and I want to hide the element with the `href` that points to `#something_else` if its first sibling (or the first child of the parent element) has the class `string`.

```
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">blah blah</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">blah blah blah></a>
</div>
```

I know this is possible using JS / jQuery, e.g.

```
if ($('.description').children().first().hasClass('string')) {
  $('a[href="#something_else"]').hide();
}
```

but it possible with only CSS?

Comment: The `a` that points to `#something_else` is not the first sibling or child of the element that has class = string. I assume you want to replicate the jQuery behavior with CSS (even though the description seems a bit off).

Comment: I meant the first child of the parent element -- which has class `description`

Comment: Ok, but the *first sibling* part is still confusing a bit. Hope one of the answers given below help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's perfectly possible, at least for browsers that are IE7 or higher.

Here's how:

```css
.description *.string:first-child ~ a[href='#something_else'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">blah blah</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">blah blah blah></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below selector. It will select (and style/hide) all the `a` (anchor) tags whose `href` is `#something_else` and is a sibling of the `span` which is the first child of its parent and has its class as `string`.

(*I have set the `color` of the required element to `red` instead of hiding it for demo purpose.*)

```css
.description span.string:first-child ~ a[href="#something_else"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">blah blah</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">blah blah blah></a> <!-- this will be selected -->
</div>

<div class="description">
  <span class="notstring">blah</span>
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">blah blah</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">blah blah blah></a> <!-- this will not be selected -->
</div>
```

**Note:** If the element (first child) with `class="string` is not always a `span` then Sarhanis' answer is the best but if it is always a `span`, I would recommend not using `*` (more a personal preference but mainly because of [(why) is the CSS star selector considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful)).

Comment: The performance concerns with * only apply when it's used alone. `*.string:first-child` is *exactly* the same as `.string:first-child` - whether you include the * there is purely stylistic.

Comment: @BoltClock: But will `span.string` and `*.string` be the same in terms of performance?

Comment: Assuming all `.string` elements are spans? I don't know. And honestly I haven't yet seen a case where it actually mattered.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree and which is why I also mentioned it is more of a personal preference as well. And I also don't know if all `.string` are `span` (as I type that I found a couple of wrong sentences in my answer :P).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using javascript or jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('.description').children().first().hasClass('string')) {
  $('a[href="#something_else"]').hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">blah blah</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">blah blah blah></a>
</div>
```

see working example here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```css
.description span.string ~ .link[href="#something_else"] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">blah</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">link 1</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">link 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   .string+a[href="#something"] {
   color:red;
   }
```

You could use the above code heres the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gmp4d5ya/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, like this:

```css
.description { margin:1em; }

.link[href="#something_else"] { display:none; }
.string + .link + .link[href="#something_else"] { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="description">
  <span class="string">string</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">something</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">something_else</a>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <a class="link" href="#something">something</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">something_else</a>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <span >not a string</span>
  <a class="link" href="#something">something</a>
  <a class="link" href="#something_else">something_else</a>
</div>
```