# Select whole body except a class in body

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the look of all anchor tags in the body except ones in the `navbar`, I tried:

```
a:not(.navbar) a {
    color: #333;
}

a:hover:not(.navbar): {
    color: #999;
}
```

But it doesn't work, all  tags became the same.
Is this possible?

**EDIT**: I have some other attributes such as transitions as well, so I can't set the restore the values for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code is quite self-explanatory, but I'll explain it:

Select all divs except the ones with class "navbar", and to all links inside those apply certain styles.

```
div:not(.navbar) a {
    color: #333;
}

div:not(.navbar) a:hover {
    color: #999;
}
```

```css
div:not(.navbar) a {
  color: red;
}
div:not(.navbar) a:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">link should NOT be red</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @n00dl3 it should but I'm not sure if its [good for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful)

Comment: Yes, it will, but Alvaro is right, the performance is very poor when using `*` selector.

Comment: If the anchor tag is very deep inside, like in another few `div`,`ul` and `li`, will it still work? Is it possible to get it to work?

Comment: `:not()` is not good for performance neither, I'm just talking of what will work even if it's not wrapped in a div.

Comment: @pleasega as long as the link is not a children of that div it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried selecting `.navbar a` tags and restoring their values?

```
a {
    color: #333;
}

a:hover {
    color: #999;
    transition: color 2s;
}

.navbar a,
.navbar a:hover {
    color: initial;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning above but I have some other attributes as well, bunch of transitions, the above was just to get hold of the logic.

Comment: You should still be able to keep those; just override the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for `.navbar a` type selectors with the `color: ` property.

Comment: The transitions and all other styles will still be there. you only overwrite what you need. And, in general, is better to use selectors/pseudo-selectors that have enough cross-browser support (and `:not` don't fit that well here).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanted my body anchor tags to have those transitions but the navbar anchor tags not to. If it was the opposite I would be able to use it, or a better way I would too.

Comment: Then override those transitions within the `.navbar a` selector. See updated answer.