# Remove word break in navigation dropdown

Tags: html, css

I try to remove the break between "Startseite" and the number on the dropdown below "News", whatever I try it always wraps

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ftnvvqcb/)

I tried to get

```
#navigation nav #main-list li ul li
```

to stop the wrap but none of the css wrap functions worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#navigation nav #main-list li ul {

    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I note that your CSS can be simplified:

- Avoid `*` rules, [they are expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful) and resetting margins and padding to zero messes-up defaults which can harm readability unless you're going to go through the effort of manually setting them for every element you're using.
- Your menu does not work when the browser window is narrow.
- `float: left;` is now obsolete for stacking elements horizontally. Consider using `display: inline-box` instead, which also gives you more control over appearance and means you can avoid having to use `clear`.
- Even with `float` you don't need a manual `<div class="clearer">` anymore, use the `::after` pseudo-element instead:

  ```
  (container of floating elements)::after {
      display: block;
      content: " ";
      clear: both;
  }
  ```
- Your `nav` element is being wasted in this context. Consider replacing your `<div id="navigation">` with just `<nav>` and eliminating the inner `<nav>` element.
- Your `<div id="wrapper">` isn't serving any purpose in this example. Also, consider replacing it with a simple `<section>` element, which makes your markup (slightly) more semantic.

Comment: What do you mean with: when the browser window is narrow? For the wrapper: this is by far not finished, it will serve its purpose later. Thanks for the other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#navigation nav #main-list li a`.

See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftnvvqcb/1/):

```
#navigation nav #main-list li a {
    display: block;

    padding: 0 12px;

    color: #eee;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as its OK for you to be editing the code manually, you can do this very simple change.

replace:

```
<li><a href="/">Startseite&nbsp;1</a></li>
```

with

```
<li><a href="/">Startseite&nbsp;1</a></li>
```

`&nbsp;` stands for Non Breaking Space, which is exactly what you need.