# CSS Specificity and Inheritance

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

Given the following code:

```css
* {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate explicabo fugiat laborum minus ullam? Amet delectus facilis id quam temporibus.
  </p>
</div>
```

The result is that the `<p>` tag has 18px font-size applied.
But shouldn't every element that is inside of the div container inherit the font-size I apply to it?
Regardless of the `*` selector applying the font-size to the `<p>` tag, 
because a tag is only worth 1 point and a class is worth 10 points?

Comment: The `*` applies the `font-size: 18px;` directly to the child `<p>` element. A style directly applied to a child element will take precedent over their inherited styles. If you wanted the `.container` children to be an exception, you could do `.container * { font-size:  50% }` or `.container p { font-size: 50%; }`,  `.container { font-size: 50%; } .container p { font-size: inherit; }`, etc. Or even use an `!important`...

Comment: To do this you need to add this: `p{font-size: inherit;}` This overrides the style applied by `*`

Comment: So i should be more careful with the * selector or i have to redefine everything later on. I will use .container * {rule} Thanks you two. :)

Comment: Correct. Otherwise you'll run into tons of overlap, or you'll be throwing `!important` attributes around like crazy, which is a generally sloppy practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.container` rule doesn't match the `p` element. So specificity is irrelevant here. Inheritance and specificity are separate concepts and the only time they interact is when more specific/less specific rules contain declarations with `inherit`. That is not the case here.

As far as the `p` element is concerned, only the `*` rule applies, and the `*` contains its own `font-size` declaration, and so the specified font size follows that declaration.

If the `*` rule didn't have its own `font-size` declaration, *then* the `p` element would inherit from `.container`.

If you want descendants of `.container` to take after its font size, you will need an additional `.container *` rule. Be *very* careful with the `inherit` keyword when it comes to relative values, though — you probably meant to keep all descendants the same size, so `1em` or `100%` is more appropriate here than `inherit`:

```css
* {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  font-size: 50%;
}

.container * {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate explicabo fugiat laborum minus ullam? Amet delectus facilis id quam temporibus.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The * takes precedence over the parent selector as you did for container. 
You should be able to reach your point adding to the p

```
font-size: inherit;
```

Or also this should work:

```
.container * {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The star * is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single element of any type.
Please see this link, has a good explanation
[(why) is the CSS star selector considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/why-is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful)