# Use *{margin:0; padding:0;} if I link normalize.css?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and I am watching tutorials on [YouTube](https://youtube.com).
The author decided to use `normalize.css` and also used `* {margin:0; padding:0;}` in `style.css`.

I thought `normalize.css` already contains that code and we do not have to specify `* {margin:0; padding:0;}` again. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the latest version of 
[normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css), it doesn't reset any elements' padding. Therefore, you may need to including padding: 0 to fit your need.

However, it's generally not a good practice to use * instead of specifying an elements or class. Here's another answer about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714096/is-the-css-star-selector-considered-harmful-and-why).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`normalize.css` won't reset css like `*{}`, it's not a good way to set css. Many elements such like `p` you may want to keep `margin`. And if you want to clean body's margin, it's already done.

Here is what [`normalize.css`](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css) do:

- Preserves useful defaults, unlike many CSS resets.
- Normalizes styles for a wide range of elements.
- Corrects bugs and common browser inconsistencies.
- Improves usability with subtle modifications.
- Explains what code does using detailed comments.